# IBM HTTP SERVER Configuration for WAS Liberty plugin

Tags: websphere-liberty, ibmhttpserver

I have installed IBM HTTP server 8.5 version, I have to configure my WebSphere application Liberty plugin  files,

> http.config

I have followed as per IBM Guidelines for the same. but I got exception while start the server.

i[image]n

environment : windows 2012 R2, WAS Liberty with MFP8.0

Please advice me

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you didn't load the WebSphere Plug-in apache module in httpd.conf w/ the `LoadModule` directive. That's nearly step 1.

Since the `WebSpherePluginConfig` directive is provided by the WAS WebServer Plug-in module, the error you showed is the first sign that you've got a problem.

One quick way to do the basic setup for IHS w/ liberty, in IHS V9, is to run the "simplepct.bat" scrpt in the bin/ directory. Otherwise, follow the instructions in the Liberty manual.